# Is there a way to quantify the 'unsortedness' of a given vector/1D array with respect to a reference vector.?

Tags: linear-algebra, information-theory

I've been working on a statistical learning problem and seem to have hit a roadblock. It's basically regarding somehow measuring how randomized or unsorted a given vector is, with respect to a reference vector.

E.g if the reference vector has 5 elements of the orientation: X = ABCDE, then is there a function that could return a score s for some Y = BDCAE with respect to  X?

i.e Something like:
f(ABCDE, ABCDE) = 0 (or 1)

f(BDCAE , ABCDE) = s

In case there is some straightforward way to do it, could you kindly let me know if we can have weight for each element as well, as in {A: w1, B: w2, ....}?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is anyone else thinking dot product?

Comment: Sounds pretty interesting. Let me check.

Comment: Dear Jp, as simple as it is, I think it was pretty insightful of you to suggest dot products for this. For the question I wrote, this surely is a very nice solution i.e taking X.Y,  in which I found that the product increases with the similarity in ranking of the 2 vectors.
Nevertheless, for my particular idiosyncratic problem, the Kendell Tau Measure, as suggested by 5xum, is exactly what I needed.
Thank you for the time anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Is the Kendall Tau distance close to what you need?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance

Comment: Well, right off the bat it looks like what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot! Let me have a closer look at it.